# How to make a C# Windows Forms app , converted for the Windows Store, start with Windows

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have created a Windows Forms C# app called "Desktop Web Tiles", that creates a panel with four websites that run with Microsoft Edge.

[https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/desktop-web-tiles/9pmp8f1nqcj7?activetab=pivot:overviewtab](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/desktop-web-tiles/9pmp8f1nqcj7?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab)

I converted the app with Desktop Bridge for Windows Store and published it. The only problem is I cannot make the Windows Store app run at startup for the end user. Looking around I found this link:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/#V6oroyVxClAEehF6.97

It says to  use the "windows.startupTask" Extension in my app manifest to make the app autostartup. The problem is I don't know much about handling the app manifest and I am stuck. It is essential for my app to start with windows, because it is fundamental for its usage. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is I don't know much about handling the app manifest and I am stuck.

If you used `Desktop Bridge` you will find `Package.appxmanifest` file where in the **Windows Application Packaging Project**, Then double click appxmanifest file - > press <kbd>F7</kbd> view code-> Add the following to appxmanifest file.

```
xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap desktop">

  ......

<Applications>
  <Application Id="App"
    Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
    EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">

  .....

    <Extensions>
      <desktop:Extension
 Category="windows.startupTask"
 Executable="DesktopApp\DesktopApp.exe"
 EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
        <desktop:StartupTask
          TaskId="MyStartupId"
          Enabled="false"
          DisplayName="TestWinFormApp" />
      </desktop:Extension>
    </Extensions>
  </Application>
</Applications>
```

Run your app and enable app's startup in the startup list. For detail steps please refer provided [blog](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/08/01/configure-app-start-log/#V6oroyVxClAEehF6.97). For better understanding I share appxmanifest [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/DeskTopStartUp/blob/master/DeskTopStartUp/Package.appxmanifest#L3).

Comment: Hi,  first of all thank you for your time. I tried what you said and it gives me error at "<desktop:Extension" and at "<desktop:StartupTask>.

Comment: Have you add this line `xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"`?

Comment: Yes you are right, after I added the line the error went away. But now it gives me a warning at: <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />.

Comment: Please add this link  `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"`

Comment: This line exists but the warning persists. Should I try publishing the app ignoring the warning?

Comment: you could ignore this warning and publish the app successful for detail steps please refer this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/07/13/a-simpler-and-faster-way-to-publish-your-desktop-bridge-applications-on-the-microsoft-store/).